# Isolated bidirectional data input/output

Tags: communication, opto-isolator, isolation

I am trying to work out how I could set up isolated bidirectional data input/output.

So far this is my schematic but I still feel like its not going to work.

is output MOSFET Q52/Q53 going to hold ISO_DIO to ground blocking incoming data?

Can anyone point out the flaws as to why this is not correct or if there is a better way of going about this?

[image]

Edit: do you think i would be thinking down the right lines if i added some kind of transmit enable that activated the PNP allowing the PNP/NPN pair to be neater high or low.

[image]

Comment: What do you call "Isolated bidirectional data input/output"? "Data pin" is I/O? Or separated data pins

Comment: Your P-MOSFETs are pointing in the wrong direction. Body diodes must be reverse biased. Source must be connected to higher voltage than drain.

Comment: Jay, if you are done here than please choose an answer for acceptance or, raise a comment seeking clarification please.

Answer (score 2):

Try redoing the P channel MOSFETs as per this: -

[image]

I'm not saying there are not other problems but the above is a showstopper.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, because of the R49 pull-up, Q53 will be activated by default, tying ISO_DIO to GND. The same behaviour will be observed on DATA_INOUT because of Q54 and R52.

You need to have a way to put the output of one of your two drivers to a high impedance state while you're using the second one to transfer data.

I'll would suggest to look for High-Z capable buffers that would allow the bidirectional line to be controlled only by one side at a time

Answer (score 0):

No, this won't work. Your data outputs are always driving into low-impedance.

In a bidirectional bus, you usually want some type of cooperation protocol. Example: maybe the right side knows that it can only go onto the bus when it receives a query from the left side.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't work for many reasons.

Q55 always shorts the IO wire to VCC.

And Q52 will always short ISO_DIO to ISO_VCC.

So both optoisolators will have their LEDs turned on.

And no communication is possible because the IOs are shorted to their supplies.

Bi-directional isolator chips do exist, if you consider it as better way.